# R Barplot: bar chart with reversed Y-axis

Tags: r, bar-chart

Imagine you have the following data set:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
ID  Wine    Beer    Water   Age Gender
1   0   1   0   20  Male
2   1   0   1   38  Female
3   0   0   1   32  Female
4   1   0   1   30  Male
5   0   1   1   30  Male
6   0   1   1   26  Female
7   0   1   1   36  Female
8   0   1   1   29  Male
9   0   1   1   33  Female
10  0   1   1   20  Female"))
```

And imagine you want to create a bar chart to plot the frequencies of those that said 'yes' (codes as '1') vs those that said 'no' (coded as '0').

generally, I would do it as follows:

```
con<-apply(df[,c(2:4)], 2, table)
con_P<-prop.table(con,2)
barplot(con_P)
```

what you end up with is a bar chart that depicts the No's at the bottom of the chart. How can you 'inverse' a bar chart in the sense that the 'Yes' are put at the bottom in each column and 'No' at the top?

I think the reason for the structure is because I first create a table and numerically '0' comes first. hence, I could just code '0' as '1' and vice versa. That would technically solve the problem. It is just not elegant. Another idea I had is `barplot(rev(con_P))` But again, it is not the same!

Any ideas? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: reverse the factor levels? or even simpler `barplot(con_P[2:1, ])`

Comment: @rawr! I am intrigued by the simplicity! Thanks so much!